# How to install all the packages that are on machine A onto machine B?

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get

I have a machine that has a bunch of user installed packages on top of a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 LTS install. I'd like to make a few machines than are essential clones, but manually looking up all the packages would be very burdensome.

Is there some way I can output a list of all user-installed packages and easily move that into a shell script that can then be run on other fresh Ubuntu installs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a start

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < (ssh othermachine dpkg --get-selections)
```

Also consider

- [puppet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29)
- [Ubuntu landscape](http://www.canonical.com/enterprise-services/ubuntu-advantage/landscape)